# Progress bar on shiny UI for file download from dropbox

Tags: r, shiny, dropbox

I have a shiny app that loads large files requested by the user from dropbox, using the drop_get() function in rdrop2, e.g:

```
drop_get(path=filename,local_file=localname,...)
```

`drop_get(,,progress=T)` shows download progress in the R console, but is there any way to show the progress in the shiny ui?

Comment: If you can convince `drop_get` to turn the counter, yes. http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/progress-bar-example.html