# Is is possible to update a Shiny progress bar when downloading a file from S3?

Tags: r, amazon-s3, shiny

I am using [AWS S3](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/aws.s3/index.html) to store files that will be downloaded from a Shiny dashboard. With the `s3load(..., with_progress = TRUE)` method I can download a file, and a progress bar is shown in the console, while the Shiny dashboard is blocked until the `s3load` method finishes. I can even use [Waiter](https://github.com/JohnCoene/waiter) to show a spinner meanwhile so the user sees that something is happening. But, can I show the actual increment in progress in Shiny? 10%... 20%... as the one printed to the console?

Methods like `capture.output` can retrieve the output os the `s3load` method, but once is finished, so I can't update the webpage on the fly.

Is it possible? What's the way?

I've seen some related but answered questions, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37338049/progress-bar-on-shiny-ui-for-file-download-from-dropbox)

**EDIT**

I've tried an approach with `capture.output` and `reactiveFileReader`, but the website only gets updated at the end, when the download is complete:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("progress")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  file.create("progress.txt")
  progressInfo <- reactiveFileReader(250, session, 'progress.txt', readLines)
  
  output$progress <- renderTable({
    progressInfo()
  })

  observe({
    capture.output(
      hc <- aws.s3::s3readRDS(path, bucket, show_progress = TRUE),
      file = 'progress.txt',
      append = FALSE,
      type = 'output'
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I assume that is because the long running operation `s3readRDS` blocks the single thread. I've checked that the file `progress.txt` is correctly updated on the fly, but `progressInfo` is not getting invalidated until the end of the download.

I suppose I need to run the long running task using the `future` package to free the main UI thread, right? Can anyone point me in the right direction to adapt my code in such a way?

Comment: If you know a priori how big the resulting file is, you can put `s3load(..)` in a background process and monitor the byte-size of the file as it is being downloaded. (I don't know `s3load`, I'm assuming there's a way to know or set what the temporary filename is...)

Comment: I know how big the file is, yes. And I know how to do all you say in other web platforms. The question is how to do it in Shiny? Do you confirm that is even possible in Shiny?

Comment: I don't know of a prebaked shiny module for this, unfortunately. Backgrounding can be done using `future` and/or `callr` packages; file-monitoring can be updated periodically with `invalidateLater` or perhaps `reactiveFileReader`; with those two parts, update a custom UI component.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my question with a first approach with your ideas

Comment: It's a start, but it's _synchronous_, meaning it is still going to block. Look into using `promises`+`future` (with or without `callr` as its backend engine) so that your call to `aws.s3::s3readRDS` does not lock up the interpreter.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to use the [`future` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/index.html) and [promise package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/promises/index.html) to run the long-running task in a separate thread or process (to allows the Shiny app to remain responsive and update the UI while the task is running), it could look like:

```r
library(future)
library(promises)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  file.create("progress.txt")
  progressInfo <- reactiveFileReader(250, session, 'progress.txt', readLines)
  
  output$progress <- renderTable({
    progressInfo()
  })

  plan(multicore) # Use multicore on macOS or Linux

  observe({
    future({
      capture.output(
        hc <- aws.s3::s3readRDS(path, bucket, show_progress = TRUE),
        file = 'progress.txt',
        append = FALSE,
        type = 'output'
      )
    }) %...>% {
      # code to run after the download is complete, if any
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Since the `multiprocess` strategy is deprecated in the version of the `future` package that you are using, on macOS, you can use the `multicore` strategy, which will take advantage of multiple cores on your machine to run tasks in parallel.
Note that `multicore` uses forked processes, which share some memory with the main process and can be more efficient in terms of memory usage compared to `multisession`, which uses completely separate R sessions.

The `future({ ... })` function call runs the downloading task in a separate process, and the `%...>%` operator is used to chain a promise to the future that is fulfilled when the task is complete. In this case, it does not do anything when the download is complete, but you can add code there if needed.

This will allow the Shiny app to stay responsive and update the progress bar while the file is downloading. The `reactiveFileReader` will keep reading the `progress.txt` file every 250 milliseconds and update the progress bar in the UI.

You will also need to handle errors that may occur during the download. You can add a `.catch` block after the `%...>%` operator to handle any exceptions that may be thrown by the future.

---

> The `progress.txt` file is updated but the UI is only refreshed at the end, with the 100% of the download completed (same UI behaviour as in the original example from the question, I mean).
> Maybe is there anything missing?

It could mean the `capture.output` function is capturing the output of the download progress, but it does not write the output to the file until the entire download is complete.

To update the progress in real-time, you would need to write the progress to the file incrementally as the download proceeds. However, since `s3load` does not provide an option to customize how progress is logged, you may need to use a different approach.

One approach could be to use a custom function to download the file from S3 in chunks, and update the progress file after each chunk is downloaded. You can use the [`aws.s3` package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/aws.s3/versions/0.3.21)'s [`s3HTTP` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/aws.s3/versions/0.3.21) for lower-level access to the S3 object, and download the file in chunks.

Furthermore, Shiny runs on a single-threaded model, and while using `future` and `promises` allows long-running operations to be executed without blocking the main thread, the Shiny application itself still operates within a single thread.
This means that while the download is being processed in a separate R process, the updates to the `progress.txt` file might not be seen by the Shiny app until the future is resolved and control is returned to the Shiny process.

A possible workaround is to use the [`later` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/later/index.html), which allows you to schedule a function to be invoked after a specified delay in the Shiny event loop.
This can be used in conjunction with `promises` and `future` to ensure that Shiny gets a chance to update the UI while the download is in progress.

```r
library(aws.s3)
library(future)
library(promises)
library(shiny)
library(later)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("progress")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  file.create("progress.txt")
  progressInfo <- reactiveFileReader(250, session, 'progress.txt', readLines)
  
  output$progress <- renderTable({
    progressInfo()
  })
  
  plan(multicore) # Use multicore on macOS or Linux
  
  observe({
    future({
      total_size <- s3HTTP(verb = "HEAD", bucket = YOUR_BUCKET, path = YOUR_PATH)$headers$`content-length`
      chunk_size <- 1024 * 1024 # 1MB
      num_chunks <- ceiling(total_size / chunk_size)
      
      for (i in 1:num_chunks) {
        range <- paste0("bytes=", (i - 1) * chunk_size, "-", i * chunk_size - 1)
        chunk <- s3HTTP(verb = "GET", bucket = YOUR_BUCKET, path = YOUR_PATH, headers = list(Range = range))
        # Append chunk to file (implement saving logic here)
        
        # Update progress
        write(paste0("Progress: ", round(i / num_chunks * 100), "%"), "progress.txt")
        
        # Yield control to Shiny event loop
        later::run_now()
      }
    }) %...>% {
      # code to run after the download is complete, if any
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The [`later::run_now()` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/later/versions/1.3.0/topics/run_now) is called after each chunk is downloaded and the progress is updated. This function causes any scheduled functions (including Shiny reactive updates) to be invoked immediately.
This should allow the Shiny app to see updates to the `progress.txt` file and update the progress bar while the download is in progress.

That would use `s3HTTP` to download the file in chunks and write the progress to the `progress.txt` file after each chunk is downloaded.
This is just to illustrate the approach, and you will need to implement the logic to save the chunks to a file and replace `YOUR_BUCKET` and `YOUR_PATH` with the appropriate values. And surely add some error handling and edge cases, as this is a simplified example!

---

> Sadly, it still shows a frozen U

Since the usual approach to running asynchronous code in Shiny does not seem to be effective in this case, another approach would be to use a separate R script to handle the downloading process and write progress to a file, which the Shiny app then reads to update the progress bar.

Meaning:

1. Shiny app triggers the download process by running a separate R script using `system2` in the background. The separate R script is responsible for downloading the file from S3 and writing progress to a file.
2. The Shiny app uses `reactiveFileReader` to monitor the file where progress is being written and updates the progress bar in the UI based on the contents of the file.

For instance:

**download_script.R**

```
library(aws.s3)

args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
bucket <- args[1]
path <- args[2]
progress_file <- args[3]

total_size <- s3HTTP(verb = "HEAD", bucket = bucket, path = path)$headers$`content-length`
chunk_size <- 1024 * 1024 # 1MB
num_chunks <- ceiling(total_size / chunk_size)

for (i in 1:num_chunks) {
    range <- paste0("bytes=", (i - 1) * chunk_size, "-", i * chunk_size - 1)
    chunk <- s3HTTP(verb = "GET", bucket = bucket, path = path, headers = list(Range = range))
    # Append chunk to file (implement saving logic here)
    
    # Update progress
    write(paste0("Progress: ", round(i / num_chunks * 100), "%"), progress_file)
}
```

**Shiny app**

```
library(shiny)
library(later)

ui <- fluidPage(
    uiOutput("progress")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    file.create("progress.txt")
    progressInfo <- reactiveFileReader(250, session, 'progress.txt', readLines)
    
    output$progress <- renderTable({
        progressInfo()
    })
    
    observe({
        # Run the download script in the background
        system2("Rscript", args = c("download_script.R", "YOUR_BUCKET", "YOUR_PATH", "progress.txt"), wait = FALSE)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In this approach, the Shiny app is running the download script in a completely separate process, which should prevent it from blocking the Shiny app's main thread and allow the progress bar to update in real time.

Comment: Hi! I am using Mac and `plan(multiprocess)` crashes with `Error : Strategy 'multiprocess' is defunct in future (>= 1.32.0) [2023-03-06]. Instead, explicitly specify either 'multisession' (recommended) or 'multicore'.`, so I am using `multiprocess`.

Comment: I've checked your modifications, and the `progress.txt` file is updated but the UI is only refreshed at the end, with the 100% of the download completed (same UI behaviour as in the original example from the question, I mean). Maybe is there anything missing? @VonC

Comment: @thelawnmowerman I have edited the original answer to use `multicore`. And added a section to address your second comment.

Comment: Tnx!! I see you are extracting the actual percentage now from the output. I could've done that, but tnx! The problem is that the UI is still frozen... Nothing is updated until the end of the download.

Comment: My only problem, from the beginning, is that the UI is frozen, nothing else.

Comment: @thelawnmowerman I have edited the second part of this answer to propose a workaround.

Comment: Tnx you very much for all the efforts. I give u the bounty, since u deserve it, but sadly it still shows a frozen UI... As soon as I have time I will check it deeply to find out why it doesn't work... BTW, have u actually run it?

Comment: @thelawnmowerman No, I tried to adapt the code using known functions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254165/discussion-between-vonc-and-thelawnmowerman).